# Google Now cards not loading

Tags: google-now, google-apps

For the last week or so, whenever I go to the Google Now page (swiping right from the home screen with the google now launcher), I don't get any Google Now cards. No weather, recommended news, etc.

If I try to reload the page by pulling the screen down, it loads for a while but nothing happens.

I've already tried reinstalling the launcher, deleting the Google Now cache and deleting the card preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by deleting all data for the Google App (including search history).

Answer (score 1):

Google now is not supported everywhere.
Check these links:

[See or remove cards in your feed](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2819541?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=0)

[Turn your feed on or off](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2824784?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en)

Here are few things:

1. Check what account are you signed in to google app. If your google account from an unsupported country then cards wouldn't show.
2. Cards also depend on your location. If you are in an unsupported country then, no cards!

If you want to enable now card in unsupported country then check below links:

[Enable Now Cards: No ROOT needed](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/guide-enable-google-cards-country-t3102472)

[Enable Now Cards [Root Needed]](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/09/23/unleashthegoogle-unlocks-a-manual-switch-for-experimental-google-now-cards-including-two-we-havent-seen-before-apk-download-root-only/)

Comment: I live in Germany and until  a week ago I could see the cards, so I'm positive they are supported here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to delete your entire phone cache data. It solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. I'm not in an unsupported area.. I'm at home where it always used to work. Started about a week or so ago.
If I restart the phone it works again.. but eventually stops. I'll try the cache suggestion.

BUG !